# How to set only one word in a specific color using Click.secho

Tags: python, click

I'm using the click module.

```
pip install click
```

This gives me red text

```
import click
click.secho('Error: This error is ...xx', fg='red')
```

Now I want that only 'Error:' is shown in red. How can I do this using `click.secho`?

Comment: `click` `echo` supports the use of `colorama` package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel and how can this help me?

Comment: click.echo('\033[31m' + 'Error:' + '\033[30m' + ' This error ... ')

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `click.echo` with `click.style`

```
click.echo(click.style("Error", fg="red") + ": This error is...")
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the built in `secho` command with the `nl` (new line) flag.

In your specific use case it would look like

```
click.secho('Error', fg='red', nl=False) # This will prevent the secho statement from starting a new line
click.echo(': This error is ...xx')
```

This will give you the output you wanted

Answer (score 7):

From `click` documentation for the [echo method](http://click.pocoo.org/5/api/#click.echo)

> In addition to that, if colorama is installed, the echo function will
>   also support clever handling of ANSI codes.

From [`colorama`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) documentation

```
print('\033[31m' + 'some red text')
print('\033[30m') # and reset to default color
```

Thus, combining, you should have something like the following

```
click.echo('\033[31m' + 'Error:' + '\033[30m' + ' This error ... ')
```

to get what you were looking for.

Comment: This is not an ideal way of doing this - the `click` library is supposed to be a high-level abstraction of low-level things like ANSI terminal codes. The other answers use `click` directly, including its named styles features.

Comment: @Bill I completely agree!

Comment: Technically this doesn't answer the specific question, which is about using `secho` to color only one word in a line. @bluesummers answer below is more specific to the question.